# Two Dimensional Array Build and Parse

Tags: jquery, regex, arrays

I apologize if this sort of thing has been covered, but I could not find anything close enough to what I want to be usable.

I have a very long list of attributes. I would like to break this up into a 2 dimensional array.

This is the format of each 'object' in my list; [[name][attr1][attr2][attr3]] and so forth. The number of attr varies, but each object starts and ends with the double brace.

Thus, I would like to store each object as an array entry, then within that array entry, break up the single brace parts into another array.

This is what I have so far;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var objGet = $(".HIDE").text().trim().split(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g);

    $.each(objGet, function() {
        var objStat = objGet.split(/\[(.)\]/g);
    });
});
```

I know that I'm doing the second level part completely wrong. I know how to break up a basic list, but not to then break up the array entry into another array. I also don't know how to output the object and its stats. Ideally, I'd like the output to be in this sort of html format:

```
obj1 = <p><span>name</span><span>attr1</span><span>attr2</span></p>
obj2 = <p><span>name</span><span>attr1</span><span>attr2</span></p>
etc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post more than one "object" in your list please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like

```
var parsed = $.map(objGet, function(val) {
   return val.split(/\[(.)\]/g);
});
```

for that second function. Map returns a new array containing the results of the function applied to each item, so this should work.

Comment: If i wanted to work on an attr of an object, how would I do this? Lets say for example, I want to add a css property to attr3 of obj7.